# Hatching in NetLogo by fractional probabilities

Tags: simulation, probability, netlogo

I'm trying to hatch a certain amount of turtles according to some statistics I've complied about births in a particular country.

To save you the math there are 201 births everyday in the adult population of 3565765.

What I want to do is scale my numbers to correspond to a netlogo model with 73 adults, 19 children and 8 toddlers so one hundred agents in total. (I've scaled these numbers according to their population distribution)

The birth rate defined by the user at the interface and currently I have..

```
to births

    ask n-of(count adults * birth-rate) adults[                                            

  hatch-toddlers 1

.....
```

The way I'm currently deciding the birth rate is 201(average births per day)/3565765(adult population) = 0.00005636939 x 73(my adult population in model) = 0.00411496551

when I get work through by code with this figure I get a birth rate of 0.30039248239. When I run my model no new toddlers are born. **Can I assume that ask n-of will only hatch a new toddler if its over 1?**

If so is there a way I can use these probabilities to slip a coin so to speak to see a turtle is hatched?

Answer (score 0):

Right, `n-of` will discard the fractional part of any number you pass it.

I think you want [`random-poisson`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#random-poisson) here.  To demonstrate its usage, suppose I want an average of 0.1 births to occur every tick. Then:

```
to demo
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  while [ticks < 100] [
    let births random-poisson 0.1
    if births > 0 [
      crt births
      print (word births " born on tick " ticks)
    ]
    tick
  ]
  print (word "after 100 ticks, there are " count turtles " turtles")
end
```

Where a typical run ends up looking like:

```
observer> demo
1 born on tick 2
1 born on tick 7
1 born on tick 12
1 born on tick 28
1 born on tick 39
1 born on tick 48
1 born on tick 49
1 born on tick 52
2 born on tick 58
1 born on tick 66
after 100 ticks, there are 11 turtles
```

On the average, you'll get 10 turtles.